# How to change legend orientation in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, qgis-2.18

I created a legend in the print composer and the default layer orientation is

[image]

How can i change the legend elements orientation like in ArcGIS?

[image]

I seeked in the Item properties but didn't found any hint.

Comment: As a work around you could have two legends, one with the text and one with the boxes side by side in the order you wanted them. For example the legend in: https://c3.staticflickr.com/4/3849/15311770866_0c01b26cc6_k.jpg was done by stacking two legends on top of each other.

Comment: @Vesanto - Not enough blues...

Comment: @Joseph almost none, perhaps next time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible as there is already an existing ticket which was updated a year ago:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3239

Answer (score 3):

I think Joseph is right, there doesn't seem to be a way. Found a couple of workarounds. Vesanto's suggestion of using a separate text box for your labels, and removing the labels from the legend, is also worth looking at if you want to stay in QGIS.

**Edit in inkscape**

If you're familiar with InkScape, you could

- hide all layers except the legend
- export to SVG,
- open it up in InkScape,
- edit it there using the group/ungroup and align tools,
- save it and bring it back in as an image (either as SVG or bitmap)

Here's an example:-

[image]

You might find you need to experiment a bit to get good results, especially with SVG. And if using Inkscape, remember to add in a background as the default is transparent.

**"Creative" suggestion**

Just for fun I found a workaround. It's not practical and the results don't look too professional ;-)

[image]

- use one of the many 'flip and mirror text' sites. These convert text to upside down equivalents (really, unicode characters will look similar to upside-down and/or back-to-front characters). For example [this site](http://www.upsidedowntext.com/)
- edit each legend item, copying and pasting the rotated text in. Make sure you choose flip AND mirror.
- set legend rotation to 180 degrees

This will only work with basic Latin characters (e.g. English A-Z and 0-9). It will not work on all fonts; you'll need to use one of your system fonts which has good unicode support. Also, your legend will appear at the bottom...

There are plenty of upside-down fonts on the web, but not seen any which are also mirrored. If you can find one this might almost work..